# Python requests module - Retrieve requests.history upon completion or error

Tags: python, python-2.7, redirect, error-handling, python-requests

I am using Python and the requests module to follow redirects for any link. I have the following code:

```
import requests

r = requests.get("put link here")
print r.history
```

This code enables me to retrieve the history of the redirects, which is something that I want. However, from time to time, I would get an error when being redirected from a link:

```
# Sometimes links in the beginning, in between, or even in the end throws an error.
r = requests.get("put link here")
```

The error can be caused by a number of issues. Is it possible for me to obtain all the redirects up to and including the link that caused an error ? For instance:

```
starting_link -> good_link1 -> good_link2 -> bad_link -> X (causes program to crash)
```

I would like to obtain:

```
starting_link -> good_link1 -> good_link2 -> bad_link
```

Is this possible with the requests module?

Thanks!

Examples:

```
# Good redirect since it will redirect you to https://www.yahoo.com (note the http -> https)
good_link = http://www.yahoo.com 

# Bad redirect
# Apologies, but I cannot provide you with an exact link. But it involves clicking a link that redirects you to "market://details?id=XXXXX"
# The requests module thinks that this is not a valid link (it is a valid 'link' in an Android phone)
```

Comment: could you give me a couple of links to test please? I am just checking if I can help you with the solution. give me links with good redirect and bad redirects if the links you are working on are public.

Comment: I added a good redirect link. The bad ones are harder to find. I will update this post when I can provide you with one.

Comment: thank you. just so you know for the crash part of your problem it is a simple exception catching code. I will include a sample for you if I can find a solution for the history.

Comment: Thanks. Catching the crash is straight forward. The hard part is getting the history.

Comment: I am curious, could you show me the error message when the program crashes, because if I skip the exception, I still can get a partial history if the url is 404 for example.